# What's the meaning of "to wave someone on"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please explain to me what "to wave someone on" as in the below situation means. I cannot find the explanation on other dictionaries. Thanks a lot!

"Did you hear me?" Hazel demanded. "We're in a lot of danger"
The policeman stepped back from the car. "I said, you better get on home."
"You're not from around here, are you?" she asked him. "I mean you weren't born here."
He looked back at her, uncertainty in his face for the first time. Then his eyes hardened and **he waved them on**.

Comment: I would like to add one more information that Hazel was with his brother in the car at that time. Thank you!

Comment: You can explain it as "He waved (his hand at) them (as a sign to go) on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal sense is that he waved his hand to indicate that they should proceed onwards. However, the actual waving isn't significant - the phrase conveys the meaning that the policeman indicated that they should move past him.

> From definition 2 (verb) of **wave**:
>   If you wave someone away or wave them on, you make a movement with your hand to indicate that they should move in a particular direction.
>   [- reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/wave)

Comment: Glad to help. There will often be multiple answers, so you might want to wait a while. Once you're satisfied with an answer, mark it by clicking on the 'tick'.